# CSS: Image touching edge of screen

Tags: css

Check out this web page: <s>http://dev.driz.co.uk/attachment.html</s><sup>***dead link***</sup>

As you will see you get a sidebar fixed and a div that is positioned absolute and allows a user to scroll around a giant image. All works great, expect that if you scroll to the right you will see that the image is touching the edge of the screen and does not have the 40px padding like the rest of the content? Any ideas why?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float this div left

```
 div#attachment div.padding {
        float: left;
        padding: 40px;
 }
```

Comment: floating it or setting a width for the containing div would work. `div.padding` was extending beyond the containing div.

Answer (score 1):

This would also work:

```
<div class="padding" style="position: inherit;">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/1440x900/00aeff/fff">
</div>
```